# Slice a tensor using tensor indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `img` in TF representing an image, whose shape is `(n_channels, img_height, img_width)`.

I also have a couple of integer tensors, `h_start`, `h_end`, `w_start`, `w_end`.

I want to extract the part of the image that corresponds to what in numpy would be `img[:, :, h_start:h_end, w_start:w_end]`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.Tensor.__getitem__`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__) pretty much like with NumPy indexing:

```
img[:, h_start:h_end, w_start:w_end]
```

Alternatively, use [`tf.slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice):

```
sliced_img = tf.slice(img, [0, h_start, w_start], [-1, h_end - h_start, w_end-w_start]
```