# How to use tensorflow to slice a Tensor phase

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I use tensorflow to slice a Tensor phase:

```
tensor = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5] ] )
    list = [0,2]
```

I want to get the result tensor:

```
result_tensor = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slice a tensor using tensor indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359922/slice-a-tensor-using-tensor-indices)

Answer (score 1):

```
tensor =tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5] ] )
lst = [0,2]
tensor[:, lst[0]:lst[1]+1]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28036632)

Comment: if th list is [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2]],how to use tensorflow API to achieve ?
tensor[:, lst[0]:lst[1]+1]

Answer (score 0):

```
tensor =tf.constant([[6,2,3,4,5],[1,7,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5] ] )

new_tensor = tf.slice(tensor,[0,0],[-1,3])
print(new_tensor)
```

This outputs

```
tf.Tensor(
[[6 2 3]
 [1 7 3]
 [1 2 3]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    sess=tf.Session()
    def sess_print(tensor):
        print(sess.run(tensor))
    
    tensor = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5] ] )
    sess_print(tf.slice(tensor,[0,0],[3,3]))
```

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
```